# ViewPager OnPageChangeListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a custom ViewPager and ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener doesn't work when I slide to a new page. What might be the reason?

```
mPager = (WrapContentHeightViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is the page you want.
        currentFav = position;
        Log.i("currentFav pos", currentFav+"");
    }
});
```

Comment: `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener doesn't work when I slide to a new page` can you explain more what problem you are getting?

Comment: When I slide to other page in my viewpager, there should be Logs that prints currentFav but I can't see them.

Comment: I am trying to remove the currentFav from the viewpager. CurrentFav should be the page number which is position so that's why I am trying to assign position to currentFav. However, onPageListener is not listening when I slide the page and I can't get the position. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: change new viewpager.OnPageChangeListener() to new OnPageChangeListener() its working for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using ViewPagerIndicator library so according to this library, I should have set page listener onto indicator.

```
mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            doYourThing();
        }
    });
```

Update for @powder366:

In your build.gradle file, add library into dependencies

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

In your top-level build.gradle file, add those:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

You can add indicator to your xml as following:

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                            android:id="@+id/indicator"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/blue"
                            android:padding="10dip"
                            app:fillColor="@color/circleindicatorfill"
                            app:pageColor="@color/circleindicatorempty"
                            app:strokeWidth="0dp" />
```

Get indicator as following:

```
mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);

mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentAdapter);

mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

mIndicator
         .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    }

                    public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                                               float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    }

                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        // Check if this is the page you want.
                       /* currentFav = position;
                        Log.i("currentFav pos", currentFav + "");*/
                    }
                });
```

Comment: And how do I get the indicator?