# Enable and disable search action in a tabbed activity

Tags: java, android

I have a tabbed activity with two tabs, and when I am in the second one I want to have a search action be shown in the actionbar. I do not want it to show in the first tab, only the second.

This is what I have for my LaunchActivity.java

```
public class LaunchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    int Numboftabs = 2;
    boolean searchDisabled = false;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    searchDisabled = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_launch, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    if(searchDisabled) {
        search.setEnabled(false);
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

menu_launch.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".LaunchActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? The search action shows up but doesn't hide when on the first tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Approach:

You can solve this by adding a class variable for the `MenuItem`.

```
MenuItem search;
```

Then in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` you only initialize it:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then in your `onPageChangeListener` you do this to show/hide the search item:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        search.setEnabled(false);
        search.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        search.setEnabled(true);
        search.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

That should achieve what you want to do.

2. Approach:

Alternative better solution would be to set up the options menu in the fragment:

Add `hasOptionsMenu(true)` to your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

And set the visibility in `onCreateOptionsMenu` (also in the fragment!):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    search.setEnabled(false);
    search.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but for some reason it did not fix the issue :(

Comment: So the search item is still always shown? The visibility doesn't change?

Comment: Yeah. I switch tabs but the search item is always shown.

Comment: I just changed the first line in onPrepareOptionsMenu, does this fix the issue?

Comment: Sadly no that didn't.

Comment: Well, then my guess would be that `onPageSelected` doesn't get called. Can you check this by debugging?

Comment: Do I have to use a PageIndicator like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980540/viewpager-onpagechangelistener-doesnt-work)?

Comment: Or is there a different way to do this? Maybe from inside the fragment's class?

Comment: There exists an alternative solution, can you add your `onCreateOptionsMenu` and your menu xml?

Comment: I've edited my post with another approach. I hope, that this will solve your issue.